# optional stopping theorem conditions satisfied?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

We have $T<\infty$ a.s. for T stopping time.
Let $X_t$ be a continuous Martingale.

Is this enough to conclude $E[X_T]=E[X_0]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: let $X_t$ be a standard Brownian motion (starting at zero), and define
$$ T=\inf\{t\geq 0:X_t=1\}$$
Then $T<\infty$ almost surely, hence $X_T=1$ almost surely, so
$$ \mathbb{E}[X_T]=1\neq 0=\mathbb{E}[X_0] $$

Comment: Couldn't it be easier? A symmetric random walk also serves as a counter example, if I recall correctly.

Comment: @O. Von Seckendorff: Yes, but the question is about continuous-time martingales.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot Brownian motion was the "continuous random walk".

Comment: So, regarding the following theorem, i assume that the brownian motion is not uniformly integrable: Let $X$ be an adapted, càdlàg process with terminal value $X_\infty$. Then $X$ is an uniformly integrable martingale  iff for all stopping times $T$ $$E[X_T]=E[X_0]$$ and $X_T$ is integrable holds?

Comment: @peer: I don't think I've ever seen uniform integrability characterized that way, but I wouldn't be surprised if that were true.

Comment: @carmichael561 You can look it up in Jacod/Shyraev: Limit theorems for Stochastic Processes.